# React native animation is no working with setState function

Tags: react-native

I have this function:

```
   const moveSwitch = () => {
    setLeftStatus(!leftStatus);
    Animated.timing(xValue, {
      toValue: leftStatus ? 0 : 26,
      duration: 300,
      easing: Easing.linear,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };
```

It works if I remove the conditional option and setState.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes around this problem here is how I solved it.

Since setState function re-renders component animation was not working.

So I just created ref using useRef and updated it like this:

```
      const moveSwitch = () => {
    Animated.timing(xValue, {
      toValue: leftStatus.current ? 0 : 26,
      duration: 300,
      easing: Easing.linear,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start(event => {
      if (event.finished) {
        if (leftStatus.current) {
          return (leftStatus.current = false);
        } else {
          return (leftStatus.current = true);
        }
      }
    });
  };
```